# Android facebook login without asking user credentials

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I'm using such plugin https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect for facebook connection in my cordova app.

After user clicks the login button - he saw a window where he need enter his facebook login and password. Even if he has already login in the installed native FB app. Is there any way to use login credential from already logged in user in native app ?

Comment: Is there some reference to documentation?

Comment: Or maybe some protocol, using which i can redirect to FB app, and after that FB app redirects user back to my app?

Comment: No. You will have to use the Facebook Android SDK to make that possible.

Comment: Yes. I'm using facebook sdk and this plugin https://github.com/wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin And when user is already logged in in FB app, and clicking on login button in my app, he needs to re-enter his FB email and password. It's strange, on iphone user can login without entering data. Why is it impossible on android, maybe some article on this topic exist ?

Comment: Sounds like something you should as the plug-in developers